# SQL join on multiple columns in same tables

Tags: sql, join

I have 2 subqueries, but I'm having trouble joining columns together from the same tables.  I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM

(SELECT userid, listid 
FROM user_views_table
WHERE date='2013-05-15' AND view_type='lists') a

JOIN

(SELECT sourceid, destinationid
FROM actions_table
WHERE date='2013-05-15' AND payloadtype='lists_user' AND actiontype='delete') b

ON a.userid = b.sourceid
ON a.listid = b.destinationid;
```

If I simply end the query with `ON a.userid = b.sourceid` it works, but how can I also join these tables on another column also `ON a.listid = b.destinationid` ??

Any help appreciated.

Comment: thanks for the answers.. argh just didn't have the ";" at end of query earlier

Answer (score 283):

You need to replace the second `ON` with `AND`, like this:

```
ON a.userid = b.sourceid AND a.listid = b.destinationid;
```

Comment: It seems obvious looking back on it, but I wanted to note that an OR works as well, you just end up with a LOT of records.

Comment: @wastubbs, not 100% but I think joining with OR has terrible performance and UNION is recommended

Answer (score 92):

You want to join on condition 1 AND condition 2, so simply use the AND keyword as below

```
ON a.userid = b.sourceid AND a.listid = b.destinationid;
```