# How can i use two fields in a SELECT clause that has a "single-group group function"

Tags: sql, database, oracle, join

i need to write a query that joins a lot of queries. They are connected by an ID. The problem is that in one of the queries, the value I have to select is a "single-group group function" and i must evaluate a condition on the `ON` clause that must use a second selected column, that i'm unable to add. I'll write a lot easier example than my code:

```
Select frst.FirstResult, scnd.FirstResult 
from(
    Select something AS FirstResult, ID_to_compare as SecondResult from table
    Where -- [...]
) frst

join(
    Select something AS FirstResult, ID_to_compare as SecondResult from table2
    Where -- [...] 
) scnd 
ON frst.SecondResult=scnd.SecondResult

join(
    Select something AS FirstResult, ID_to_compare as SecondResult from table3
    Where -- [...]
) trd 
ON scnd.SecondResult=trd.SecondResult

-- [...]

join(
    Select single_group_function(params) AS FirstResult, ID_to_compare as SecondResult from table3
--This select cannot be done because of the group function cannot be executed
    Where -- [...]
) trd 
ON svn.SecondResult=eit.SecondResult
```

My problem is that i need to compare the "SecondResult" from every select, but the member group is not allowed to make a query like this. I've tried with the "dual" table but it's really messy for me and i don't understand exactly how to use it. I've also tried by joining them in a macro query, but every single select is big enough to be really confusing to write. I've taken the ideas from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16597660/sql-join-on-multiple-columns-in-same-tables) and a lot more. Have you any hint to acomplish my task?

For petition of MT0, a Minimal Complete and verificable problem is this:

```
Select frst.FirstField, scnd.FirstField, frst.SecondField
from
(Select a1.DUMMY as FirstField, a2.DUMMY as SecondField
    from dual a1 join dual a2 on 1=1) frst
  join
(Select a1.DUMMY as FirstField, a2.DUMMY as SecondField
    from dual a1 join dual a2 on 1=1) scnd
  ON frst.SecondField = scnd.SecondField

  join
  (Select sum(a1.DUMMY) as FirstField, a2.DUMMY as SecondField
    from dual a1 join dual a2 on 1=1) trd
  ON trd.SecondField = scnd.SecondField
  ;
```

I would expect in this case

```
frst.FirstField  scnd.FirstField  frst.SecondField
---------------- ---------------- --------------------
X                X                1
```

But i get instead

```
Error en la línea de comandos : 11 Columna : 40
Informe de error -
Error SQL: ORA-00937: la función de grupo no es de grupo único
00937. 00000 -  "not a single-group group function"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Comment: Can you give a [MCVE] with DDL/DML statements for some sample data and your expected output to give an illustration of a minimal version of the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. @MT0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your sample subquery:

```
Select sum(a1.DUMMY) as FirstField, a2.DUMMY as SecondField
from dual a1 join dual a2 on 1=1
```

So do you expect one result row? This is what an aggregation with no `GROUP BY` does. You'd get the sum over all records, but which `a2.DUMMY` to show in this result record? This is what the DBMS is complaining about.

What you probably want is a sum per `a2.DUMMY` instead. So group by this column:

```
Select sum(a1.DUMMY) as FirstField, a2.DUMMY as SecondField
from dual a1 join dual a2 on 1=1
GROUP BY a2.DUMMY
```

Answer (score 2):

In your simplified example you're doing:

```
  join
  (Select sum(a1.DUMMY) as FirstField, a2.DUMMY as SecondField
    from dual a1 join dual a2 on 1=1) trd
  ON trd.SecondField = scnd.SecondField
```

You can simplify further to see the problem:

```
Select sum(a1.DUMMY) as FirstField, a2.DUMMY as SecondField
from dual a1 join dual a2 on 1=1;

ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
```

You have to include any columns that you are *not* aggregating in the group-by clause:

```
Select sum(a1.DUMMY) as FirstField, a2.DUMMY as SecondField
from dual a1 join dual a2 on 1=1
group by a2.DUMMY;
```

which will now get ORA-01722, since dummy is a string; using max instead:

```
Select frst.FirstField, scnd.FirstField, frst.SecondField
from
(Select a1.DUMMY as FirstField, a2.DUMMY as SecondField
    from dual a1 join dual a2 on 1=1) frst
  join
(Select a1.DUMMY as FirstField, a2.DUMMY as SecondField
    from dual a1 join dual a2 on 1=1) scnd
  ON frst.SecondField = scnd.SecondField

  join
  (Select max(a1.DUMMY) as FirstField, a2.DUMMY as SecondField
    from dual a1 join dual a2 on 1=1 group by a2.DUMMY) trd
  ON trd.SecondField = scnd.SecondField
  ;

F F S
- - -
X X X
```

So you real query needs to do something like:

```
    Select single_group_function(params) AS FirstResult, ID_to_compare as SecondResult from table3
    Where -- [...]
    group by ID_to_compare
```

in its subquery