# SQL Conditional join based on Rank

Tags: sql

I am trying to join two tables based on Instrument and Rank. if Instrument and Rank matches then it is a direct join. Else join should seek the next available rank in order. for example if Instrument CDF and Rank 1 is not matching in Table 2 then sql query should seek CDF and Rank 2 to match. If it matches then move to next Instrument and Rank in table 1.

Output should have as many row as in Table 1 and only matched qty from table 2 based on logic above. Table 1 will not have duplicates.

Any algorithm or sample code will be a great help.

Test:

Output should have 3 rows as per sample data.

1. ABC 1 from Table 1 should match with ABC 1 from Table 2 and return qty 55.
2. CDF 1 from Table 1 should be matched to CDF 2 from Table 2 and return qty as 56.
3. CDE 2 from Table 1 should match to CDE 4 (not rank 1) from table 2 and return qty as 91.

Hope this will clarify the request.

Expected results from example data:

| Instrument | Qty |
| --- | --- |
| ABC | 55 |
| CDF | 56 |
| CDE | 91 |

Example Data

Table 1:

| Instrument | Rank | Id | position |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 1 | 2 | A1 |
| CDF | 1 | 78 | Abg |
| CDE | 2 | 65 | dfv |

Table 2:

| Ins | Qty | Rank |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 55 | 1 |
| ABC | 65 | 2 |
| ABC | 76 | 4 |
| CDF | 56 | 2 |
| CDF | 55 | 3 |
| CDF | 33 | 4 |
| CDE | 78 | 1 |
| CDE | 91 | 4 |

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL join on multiple columns in same tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16597660/sql-join-on-multiple-columns-in-same-tables)

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only the tag for the database product you are really using.

Answer (score 0):

```
select
  *,
  (
    select qty
    from table2 as t2
    where t2.instrument = t1.instrument and t2.rank >= t1.rank
    order by t2.rank limit 1
  ) as qty
from table1 as t1;
```

If you need more then one columns from the `table2` then use `cross join lateral` instead